# Срабатывает ли событие resize при изменение ориентации экрана?

Tags: javascript

Срабатывает ли событие resize при изменение ориентации экрана  на мобильных устройствах, планшетах ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, срабатывает. При срабатывании события `resize` можно узнать текущую ориентацию через [`window.screen.orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation).

Вот вам сниппет для проверки, проверяйте либо с телефона, либо на ПК перенесите код в отдельный файл, а там уже через инструменты разработчика проверьте.

```js
setText()

window.addEventListener('resize', setText)

function setText() {
  let output = document.querySelector('#output')
  let orientationType = window.screen.orientation.type

  output.textContent = orientationType.includes('portrait')
    ? 'Yes'
    : 'No'
}
```

```html
<p>Is portrait?</p>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но с ориентацией видимо придется повременить пока добавят во все браузеры. Она в safari не поддерживается

Comment: @Bakhtiyar можно ещё проверить ширину и высоту экрана и уже по ней понять ориентацию.